# Hash table, load time, in C

Tags: performance, dictionary, time, load, hashtable

I'm creating an hash table (initial array and linked lists) for a dictionary. I know the number of words I want in the dictionary. Is there a function that allows me to see how the load time changes depending on the size of the array?

I have a file that contains all the words of a dictionary. I want to load an hash table with those words. Let's say there are 10k words in the dictionary. I guess I could run 2 for loops, 1 for the array, 1 for the linked lists. For example: an array of size 10 and 1k linked lists for each array bucket. Ho do I know the time it would take, compared to, let's say, an array of size 1k and 10 linked lists?

I guess that with an array of only one bucket, it would take as many steps as the number of words (so the minimum steps), but I don't want that, since I've got also a check function, later, that would otherwise take forever to check the whole line every time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "Is there a function that allows me to see how the load time changes depending on the size of the array?" - do you mean "function" as in maths (which can give the probability distribution for the number of collisions during the insertion of all your words), or as in computer-language procedure for real-world elapsed time of some specific set of words?  If maths, you first need to know the collision-proneness of your hash function, in light of the nature of the keys.  For a great hash function, formula as a function of load factor is given [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/31882).

Comment: "I guess that with one bracket of the array, it would take as many steps as the number of words, but I don't want that, since I've got also a check function, later, that would otherwise take forever to check the whole line every time." - I guess you mean "bucket", not "bracket"?  And yes - there's no point in a hash table with one bucket.  For hash tables to work properly, you have to keep the load factor in a reasonable range - 0.5 to 1 works pretty well (hence C++'s default max_load_factor of 1.0 and typical implementation resizing by roughly - or sometimes exactly - doubling buckets).

Comment: I changed the question, I hope it's clearer now. I'm sorry, but I'm working for the right question as well, not only for the answer. :)